# insert <int,pair<int,int>> priority_queue

Tags: c++, heap, max-heap

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,int> maxh;

error:no default constructor exists for class "std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, int, <error-type>>"
```

If i try this method

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,int> maxh;
    for (int i=0;i<n,i++){
        
        int x1 =  a[i][0]*a[i][0];
        int y1 =  a[i][1]*a[i][1]; 
        
         int sum = x1 + y1;
        maxh.push(sum,make_pair(a[i][0],a[i][1]));
    }
```

`maxh.push(sum,make_pair(a[i][0],a[i][1]));` gives the error

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::push [with _Tp=std::pair<int, int>, _Sequence=std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int>>>, _Compare=int]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int, std::pair<int, int>) -- object type is: std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int>>>, int>
```

Comment: I do not understand - how do you want to push `int, std::pair<int, int>` into container with `<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,int>` elements?

Comment: priority_queue<pair<int,int>,int> maxh;
the second argument for the template of std::priority_queue is a container. Check the definition here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: You should try and explain what you are trying to achieve because your code is so confused it is not obvious. For instance here `maxh.push(sum,make_pair(a[i][0],a[i][1]))` you are trying to push two things onto the queue, but you can only push one thing at a time onto a priority queue. And its not possible for a queue to hold both integers and pairs at the same time.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that you are trying to put pairs onto your priority queue and order them by `sum`. If that's the case then that is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm taking a guess here, because you haven't explained yourself.

I'm assuming that you want to put pairs onto your priority queue and order them using these formulae that are in your code

```
int x1 =  a[i][0]*a[i][0];
int y1 =  a[i][1]*a[i][1]; 
    
int sum = x1 + y1;
```

The simplest way to do that is to use a *lambda function* that compares two pairs using the formula above. Here's some sample code

```
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    auto lambda = [](pair<int, int> x, pair<int, int> y){ 
        return x.first*x.first + x.second*x.second < 
               y.first*y.first + y.second*y.second; };
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(lambda)> maxh;
    int a[3][2] = { {1,2}, {2,2}, {1,0} };
    int n = 3;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        maxh.push(make_pair(a[i][0],a[i][1]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The lambda function is in the first line `auto lambda = ...;`. I've assumed that you want largest first. If your want smallest first just change `<` to `>` in the lambda function.

Comment: My first instinct was to use `std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>>` and `push({sum, {a[i][0], a[i][1]}})`, let the implementation handle the rest. Well, certainly yours is better, takes less memory than mine! :)

Comment: @brc-dd That approach didn't occur to me. It may well be what the OP was trying to write. The two ways seem pretty much equivalent.